# Extension Method Solution

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I've got some code to indicate when a field on my **WinForm** has changed.

If the [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) is a [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx), I alter the [ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx) and [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx) depending on if the Text of the Control is equal to the default (or initial) value.

```
private void LastName_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (sender.Equals(txtLastName)) {
    if (emp0.LastName != txtLastName.Text) {
      txtLastName.ForeColor = changedTxtFont;
      txtLastName.BackColor = changedTxtBack;
      btnOK.Enabled = true;
    } else {
      txtLastName.ForeColor = systemTxtFont;
      txtLastName.BackColor = systemTxtBack;
    }
    AuthenticationReset();
  }
}
```

If the Control is a [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) or [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx), I can't really do this (there is no visible ForeColor or BackColor), so I alter the Label that is associated with the Control.

```
private void TrainDate_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (sender.Equals(dtTrainDate)) {
    DateTime trainDate = Global.SqlDate(emp0.TrainDate);
    if (trainDate != dtTrainDate.Value) {
      lblTrainDate.ForeColor = changedLblFont;
      lblTrainDate.BackColor = changedLblBack;
      btnOK.Enabled = true;
    } else {
      lblTrainDate.ForeColor = systemLblFont;
      lblTrainDate.BackColor = systemLblBack;
    }
    AuthenticationReset();
  }
}
```

I'd like to create some sort of [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that could change the ForeColor and BackColor of a Control dependent upon what that Control is and if the value had changed.

Here is an attempt, but the use of `this` in the code is not valid and the extension methods do not show up for any of the Controls I want to use them on.

```
public static class ColorChange {

  public static Color ForeColorChange(this Color owned, bool changed) {
    if (this is TextBox) {
      return changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.WindowText;
    } else {
      return changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.ControlText;
    }
  }

  public static Color BackColorChange(this Color owned, bool changed) {
    if (this is TextBox) {
      return changed ? Color.Yellow : SystemColors.Window;
    } else {
      return SystemColors.Control;
    }
  }

}
```

Is there a way to approach what I'm trying to do or is this not what Extension Methods are for?

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
private void TrainDate_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (sender.Equals(dtTrainDate)) {
    DateTime trainDate = Global.SqlDate(emp0.TrainDate);
    if (trainDate != dtTrainDate.Value) {
      lblTrainDate.ForeColorChange(true);
      lblTrainDate.BackColorChange(true);
      btnOK.Enabled = true;
    } else {
      lblTrainDate.ForeColorChange(false);
      lblTrainDate.BackColorChange(false);
    }
    AuthenticationReset();
  }
}
```

**Solution:**

Using the answer checked below, I wrote the following Extension Method:

```
public static class ColorChange {
  public static void AlteredText(this Control owned, bool changed) {
    if (owned is TextBox) {
      owned.ForeColor = changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.WindowText;
      owned.BackColor = changed ? Color.Yellow : SystemColors.Window;
    } else {
      owned.ForeColor = changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.ControlText;
      owned.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I will be using it:

```
private void TrainDate_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (sender.Equals(dtTrainDate)) {
    DateTime trainDate = Global.SqlDate(emp0.TrainDate);
    if (trainDate != dtTrainDate.Value) {
      lblTrainDate.AlteredText(true);
      btnOK.Enabled = true;
    } else {
      lblTrainDate.AlteredText(false);
    }
    AuthenticationReset();
  }
}
```

I hope others get use out of this as well. ~Joe.

Comment: Are those methods declared in a static class?:

Comment: Yes. I do have a static class that they are defined in. Good question!

Comment: So try calling them like `(TextBox(Control)).ForeColor.ForeColorChange(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extends Control instead of Color (needs to be defined in a static class):

```
public static void ForeColorChange(this Control owned, bool changed) {
  if (owned is TextBox) {
    owned.ForeColor = changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.WindowText;
  } else {
    owned.ForeColor = changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.ControlText;
  }
}

public static void BackColorChange(this Control owned, bool changed) {
  if (owned is TextBox) {
    owned.BackColor = changed ? Color.Yellow : SystemColors.Window;
  } else {
    owned.BackColor =  SystemColors.Control;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
TextBox box = ...;
box.ForeColorChange(true);
```

Comment: +1. You're' onto something, and I'm understanding it (says a lot). The 2nd method still shows a `Color` type, but I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 4):

You've defined extension methods for the `Color` class, not `Control`, which is why it won;t show for controls. In addition, your methods probably want to inspect the `owned` control that you'll need to pass in.

Answer (score 1):

Use your `owned` instead of `this`.. oh and as Rowland Shaw says, `Control` instead of `Color`.

So your code should finally be

```
public static Color ForeColorChange(this Control owned, bool changed) {
  if (owned is TextBox) {
    return changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.WindowText;
  } else {
    return changed ? Color.Red : SystemColors.ControlText;
  }
}

public static Color BackColorChange(this Control owned, bool changed) {
  if (owned is TextBox) {
    return changed ? Color.Yellow : SystemColors.Window;
  } else {
    return SystemColors.Control;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call your extension method on your textbox, you have to do this in the toplevel of your namespace:

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static void myExtensionMethod(this Textbox textbox)
  {
    //Do what you want to do
  }
}
```

And then it is accessible over your textbox:

```
Textbox myTextbox = new Textbox();
myTextbox.myExtensionMethod();
```

If you want, you can also pass parameters to your extension method.

Comment: This technique can not be general enough to use with the Label controls, too, though. ...if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In general, it works with a Label, too. But Label does not inherit Control. So if you extend the Control class, the label does not know about it. If you **need** to have a single method that always works, you could create a custom DateTimePicker/ComboBox and attach a label there. Then these controls have a handle to the Label and the extension method can change it.